# Downloading plotly.express on VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm having a tough time trying to download plotly.express on VSCode. I keep getting this error, even though I tried downloading it via pip for both plotly.express and plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.express'; 'plotly' is not a package
```

I was wondering, how do I get around this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: By "download", do you mean using "`pip install`"? VS Code is basically just an editor, it doesn't "download" the packages, you do that with Python's pip. VS Code just helps you manage [Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). You need to make sure to run the app in the same env as where you installed plotly.

Comment: if you can run your code manually in terminal in `VS Code` - `python script.py` - then you can also run `python -m pip install plotly` to install modules in this Python. In `PyCharm` you could open settings to see which Python interpreter is used by project, and it also could display all modules installed in this Python, and you could also install new modules - but I don't know if `VS Code` (with extensions) has something similar.